# Cannot find name 'GlobalFetch despite having proper TS version

Tags: reactjs, typescript, snowpack

I am fresh building a web app repository using React/TypeScript and the app works but deployment fails:

```
> build:dev
> SNOWPACK_PUBLIC_APP_ENVIRONMENT=dev snowpack build

[@snowpack/plugin-typescript] src/api/runtime.ts(130,24): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'GlobalFetch'.
[@snowpack/plugin-typescript] Error: Command failed with exit code 2: tsc --noEmit
src/api/runtime.ts(130,24): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'GlobalFetch'.
```

Weird is the project is working on another machine, so it is not a new development, there were no source code change. SO answers on "GlobalFetch" say there was a problem with it in some 3.x version of type script, but I see the version installed has higher one:

version "4.2.3"

Any ideas on where to look for a reason?

Answer (score 0):

The `GlobalFetch` type was removed from the definitions in TS 3.6.

Your other dev environment probably uses an old version of TS.

You either have to

- downgrade your TS version
- remove the `GlobalFetch` type in your code base
- recreate the type with: `declare type GlobalFetch = WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope`

Comment: Thanks. I am only concerned with "probably". I can see and compare both environments and yarn.lock is identical. How can another machine use different TS version?

Comment: is `typescript` defined in the dependencies ? What does `tsc --version` outputs ?

Comment: "tsc command not found". Are you saying there is TS version in packages.json and one installed locally??

Comment: There can be a global tsc yes